# 9.517513---[end kernel panic - not syncing :vfs:unable to mount root fs on unkown block(0,0)

Tags: system-installation, kernel, mount, sync

I am a windows 8 user I just  tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 and downloaded ISO and burn it in on CD, but when I tried installing I got an error on:

```
9.517513---[end kernel panic - not syncing :vfs:unable to mount root fs on unkown block(0,0)
```

What does it mean? and how to recover from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burn that CD (LITERALLY) if not re-writable

Get a new one

Check the ISO Check sums from the Download Page, if they match then rewrite or else re download

Always download from official site only